# If $x^2 \geq y^2$, is the same true for their absolute values?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

Apologies to ask a question that may be extremely obvious. I've got a multi-variable function:

$f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$

I've been asked to find (and sketch) the domain of this function:

Because of the $\sqrt{}$, we know that $x^2 - y^2 \ge 0$

This means that $x^2 \ge y^2$

Would it be wrong to therefore write the domain as:

$D(f) = $ {$(x,y): |x| \ge |y|$}?

The model answer was written as:

$D(f) = $ {$x \ge \pm y, x \ge 0$} ∪ {$x \le \pm y, x \le 0 $}

Would I be right in assuming that the answer was written like this to make sketching the domain easier , and both answers are in fact correct? Any clarity on this would be of great help!

Comment: The square root is an increasing function, so $x^2\ge y^2 \implies \sqrt{x^2}\ge \sqrt{y^2}$.

Comment: As a complement to the previous comment, note that $\sqrt{x^2}\geqslant\sqrt{y^2}\iff|x|\geqslant|y|$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. $x^2\geq y^2 \iff |x|\geq|y|.$

Comment: Thanks to all of you for clarifying this.

Comment: Option: Write $(x-y) (x+y) \ge 0$, and discuss the options: Product is $\ge 0$ if both factors are $\ge 0$, or both factors are $\le 0$.

Comment: @James You can also remember that $x^{2} = |x|^{2}$ and $y^{2} = |y|^{2}$.